# Split delimited row to column in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table with values:

Table 1: Table1
    id  Hirerachy
    1   :A:B:C
    2   :P:Q:R:S:T
    3   :M:N

How can we split it as below:

Table 1: Table2
    id col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
    1   C    B    A    N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A
    2   T    S    R     Q   P    N/A  N/A
    3   N    M    N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A

The row contains delimited column changes.

Please help me by providing complete solution in SQL/PLSQL using cursors.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on implementing cursor: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answering it by myself, as i succeeded in finding the solution:

SELECT table1.id,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 0
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':'))
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col1",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 1
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-1)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col2",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 2
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-2)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col3",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 3
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-3)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col4",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 4
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-4)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col5",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 5
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-5)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col6",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 6
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-6)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col7",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 7
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-7)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col8",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 8
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-8)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col9",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 9
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-9)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col10",

CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':') > 10
    THEN regexp_substr(Hierarchy, '[^:]+', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(b.Hirerachy, ':')-10)
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END "col11"

FROM table1